# flutter how to use both globalKey and uniqueKey simultaneously

Tags: flutter

I use this StatefulWidget class StatefulWidgetSample and need to use both globalKey and uniqueKey simultaneously how can i solve this problem??

```
StatefulWidgetSample(
      // key: chipGroupGlobalKey,
      key: UniqueKey(),
      list: _labelService.getLabel(selectedType),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to? A single `Key` uniquely identifies a widget. Otherwise two `Key`s would point to the same thing.
Currently, your `UniqueKey` is also recreated on every build and therefore the state of the corresponding `StatefulWidgetSample` is recreated. Of course I don't know if you want it that way.
In principle, you could simply wrap a placeholder around it to assign a second key, but then `chipGroupGlobalKey` would still be redundant because only `UniqueKey()` is relevant:

```
SizedBox(
  key: chipGroupGlobalKey,
  child: StatefulWidgetSample(
    key: UniqueKey(),
    list: _labelService.getLabel(selectedType),
  ),
),
```

Comment: I  use chipGroupGlobalKey for getting StatefulWidgetSample state outside and need UniqueKey for respond to list change when selectedType change

Comment: And what do you need the `UniqueKey` for? The GlobalKey should already do everything you need.

Comment: respond to list change when selectedType change

Comment: Why is no `setState` call sufficient when the state changes?

Comment: I call setState outside when selectedType change , but StatefulWidgetSample not react it  so i add Unique key and  it worked..

Comment: Then it is due to a bug in the implementation of `StatefulWidgetSample`. Currently you create a new state every time, which misses the point of StatefulWidgets. You could add its code to your question.